# cmake is not using locally built dependency

Tags: c++, makefile, cmake

I have a library/api (locally build) that I want CMAKE to use, but it's using old one, listed in dependencies

My project structure: CMakeLists (lists local library to be built), service, library

The service has a dependency (this library/api) in inner CMakeLists. However, when I build it, it's taking that dependency from somewhere else.

How can specify it to use the library/api that I build couple directories above?

cmake - dependency is listed in src/src.dep
tried copying library into directory, but it can't be found

```
cmake_minimum_required( VERSION 3.14 )
read_metadata( PACKAGE src )
add_library( src STATIC ${src_SOURCE_FILES} )
target_include_directories( src PUBLIC ${src_INCLUDE_DIRS} .. )
target_link_libraries( src PUBLIC ${src_PCDEPS} )
configure_bb_target( src HEADERS ${src_INCLUDE_FILES} )
```

Comment: Sorry if it's too basic, but I could not find solution to this exact problem

Comment: "However, when I build it, it's taking that dependency from somewhere else." - What do you mean by "dependency taken from somewhere else"? It looks for the "dependency" by the name, but finds that dependency in unexpected location? Your code uses two non-standard functions - `read_metadata` and `configure_bb_target` - and we can only  guess about their meaning. If you use some framework or whatever, which control dependencies, then give us the name of that framework. It seems that the problem is not with CMake in general, but with given framework.

Comment: I may have phased it better. Those two are of a lesser importance, they just read info about this directory and pass header files

What I want to do is to remove dependency from src.dep and add it manually in cmake above. Dependency is located couple of directories above

Comment: @Tsyvarev that library/api has it's CMakeLists, and I want to say: this is a path where you can find this dependency/library/api

Comment: If your library has a cmake file, then look into it and see what target it creates. This target name you can use in your own cmake to link against. You have to add the include directories manually using `include_directories()` unless the library provides method to find itself. I suppose you have the same library installed somehwere using `apt-get` or similar and your cmake find this instead.

Comment: "What I want to do is to remove dependency from src.dep" - Among **known** commands in your `CMakeLists.txt` none command works with `src.dep`. CMake creates a library from files listed in `src_SOURCE_FILES`, includes directories specified in `src_INCLUDE_DIRS` and links with the libraries specified in `src_PCDEPS`. That's all. It is **unclear** what your problem is and how given `CMakeLists.txt` is related with your problem.